# Unable to print/scan after upgrade to 16.04

Tags: 16.04, printing

I have an HP Deskjet 3050 that used to print/scan in 14.04 - but fails to print/scan after the upgrade to 16.04 - below are the details - please help!

```
jon@faltinPC:~$ hp-check
```

Saving output in log file: /home/jon/hp-check.log

HP Linux Imaging and Printing System (ver. 3.17.4)
Dependency/Version Check Utility ver. 15.1

Copyright (c) 2001-15 HP Development Company, LP
This software comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY.
This is free software, and you are welcome to distribute it
under certain conditions. See COPYING file for more details.

Note: hp-check can be run in three modes:
1. Compile-time check mode (-c or --compile): Use this mode before compiling the HPLIP supplied tarball (.tar.gz or .run) to determine if the proper
dependencies are installed to successfully compile HPLIP.
2. Run-time check mode (-r or --run): Use this mode to determine if a distro supplied package (.deb, .rpm, etc) or an already built HPLIP supplied
tarball has the proper dependencies installed to successfully run.
3. Both compile- and run-time check mode (-b or --both) (Default): This mode will check both of the above cases (both compile- and run-time
dependencies).

Check types:
a. EXTERNALDEP - External Dependencies
b. GENERALDEP - General Dependencies (required both at compile and run time)
c. COMPILEDEP - Compile time Dependencies
d. [All are run-time checks]
PYEXT SCANCONF QUEUES PERMISSION

Status Types:
    OK
    MISSING       - Missing Dependency or Permission or Plug-in
    INCOMPAT      - Incompatible dependency-version or Plugin-version

---

### | SYSTEM INFO |

Kernel: 4.4.0-72-generic #93-Ubuntu SMP Fri Mar 31 14:07:41 UTC 2017 GNU/Linux
 Host: faltinPC
 Proc: 4.4.0-72-generic #93-Ubuntu SMP Fri Mar 31 14:07:41 UTC 2017 GNU/Linux
 Distribution: 12 16.04
 Bitness: 64 bit

---

### | HPLIP CONFIGURATION |

HPLIP-Version: HPLIP 3.17.4
HPLIP-Home: /usr/share/hplip
HPLIP-Installation: Auto installation is supported for ubuntu distro  16.04 version

Current contents of '/etc/hp/hplip.conf' file:

## hplip.conf.  Generated from hplip.conf.in by configure.

[hplip]
version=3.17.4

[dirs]
home=/usr/share/hplip
run=/var/run
ppd=/usr/share/ppd/HP
ppdbase=/usr/share/ppd
doc=/usr/share/doc/hplip-3.17.4
html=/usr/share/doc/hplip-3.17.4
icon=/usr/share/applications
cupsbackend=/usr/lib/cups/backend
cupsfilter=/usr/lib/cups/filter
drv=/usr/share/cups/drv/hp
bin=/usr/bin
apparmor=/etc/apparmor.d

## Following values are determined at configure time and cannot be changed.

[configure]
network-build=yes
libusb01-build=no
pp-build=no
gui-build=yes
scanner-build=yes
fax-build=yes
dbus-build=yes
cups11-build=no
doc-build=yes
shadow-build=no
hpijs-install=no
foomatic-drv-install=no
foomatic-ppd-install=no
foomatic-rip-hplip-install=no
hpcups-install=yes
cups-drv-install=yes
cups-ppd-install=no
internal-tag=3.17.4
restricted-build=no
ui-toolkit=qt4
qt3=no
qt4=yes
qt5=no
policy-kit=no
lite-build=no
udev_sysfs_rules=no
hpcups-only-build=no
hpijs-only-build=no
apparmor_build=yes

Current contents of '/var/lib/hp/hplip.state' file:
[plugin]
installed = 1
eula = 1
version = 3.17.4

Current contents of '~/.hplip/hplip.conf' file:
[upgrade]
notify_upgrade = true
last_upgraded_time = 1492828247
pending_upgrade_time = 0
latest_available_version = 3.16.11

[last_used]
device_uri = "hp:/usb/Deskjet_3050_J610_series?serial=CN18J3D15405HX"
printer_name = Deskjet_3050_J610
working_dir = .

[settings]
systray_visible = 0
systray_messages = 0

[commands]
scan = /usr/bin/xsane -V %SANE_URI%

[refresh]
rate = 30
enable = false
type = 1

[polling]
enable = false
interval = 5
device_list =

[fax]
voice_phone = 
email_address =

[installation]
date_time = 04/21/2017 23:14:09
version = 3.17.4

---

### | COMPILEDEP |

gcc                  gcc - GNU Project C and C++ Compiler                         REQUIRED        -               5.4.0           OK         -
 make                 make - GNU make utility to maintain groups of programs       REQUIRED        3.0             4.1             OK         -
 libtool              libtool - Library building support services                  REQUIRED        -               2.4.6           OK         -

---

### | General Dependencies |

libcrypto            libcrypto - OpenSSL cryptographic library                    REQUIRED        -               1.0.2           OK         -
 python-xml           Python XML libraries                                         REQUIRED        -               2.1.0           OK         -
 libnetsnmp-devel     libnetsnmp-devel - SNMP networking library development files REQUIRED        5.0.9           5.7.3           OK         -
 sane-devel           SANE - Scanning library development files                    REQUIRED        -               1.0.25          OK         -
 pil                  PIL - Python Imaging Library (required for commandline scanning with hp-scan) OPTIONAL        -               1.1.7           OK         -
 pyqt4-dbus           PyQt 4 DBus - DBus Support for PyQt4                         REQUIRED        4.0             4.11.4          OK         -
 libpthread           libpthread - POSIX threads library                           REQUIRED        -               2.23            OK         -
 python-devel         Python devel - Python development files                      REQUIRED        2.2             2.7.12          OK         -
 cups-devel           CUPS devel- Common Unix Printing System development files    REQUIRED        -               2.1.3           OK         -
 python-dbus          Python DBus - Python bindings for DBus                       REQUIRED        0.80.0          1.2.0           OK         -
 cups-ddk             CUPS DDK - CUPS driver development kit                       OPTIONAL        -               -               OK         -
 reportlab            Reportlab - PDF library for Python                           OPTIONAL        2.0             3.3.0           OK         -
 pyqt4                PyQt 4- Qt interface for Python (for Qt version 4.x)         REQUIRED        4.0             4.11.4          OK         -
 libusb               libusb - USB library                                         REQUIRED        -               1.0             OK         -
 cups-image           CUPS image - CUPS image development files                    REQUIRED        -               2.1.3           OK         -
 python2X             Python 2.2 or greater - Python programming language          REQUIRED        2.2             2.7.12          OK         -
 python-notify        Python libnotify - Python bindings for the libnotify Desktop notifications OPTIONAL        -               -               OK         -
 libjpeg              libjpeg - JPEG library                                       REQUIRED        -               -               OK         -
 sane                 SANE - Scanning library                                      REQUIRED        -               1.0.25          OK         -

---

### | Scan Configuration |

scanext              Scan-SANE-Extension                                          REQUIRED        -               3.17.4          OK         -
 hpaio                HPLIP-SANE-Backend                                           REQUIRED        -               3.17.4          OK         'hpaio found in /etc/sane.d/dll.conf'

---

### | External Dependencies |

gs                   GhostScript - PostScript and PDF language interpreter and previewer REQUIRED        7.05            9.18            OK         -
 cups                 CUPS - Common Unix Printing System                           REQUIRED        1.1             2.1.3           OK         'CUPS Scheduler is running'
 network              network -wget                                                OPTIONAL        -               1.17.1          OK         -
 scanimage            scanimage - Shell scanning program                           OPTIONAL        1.0             1.0.25          OK         -
 policykit            PolicyKit - Administrative policy framework                  OPTIONAL        -               0.105           OK         -
 xsane                xsane - Graphical scanner frontend for SANE                  OPTIONAL        0.9             0.999           OK         -
 dbus                 DBus - Message bus system                                    REQUIRED        -               1.10.6          OK         -
 avahi-utils          avahi-utils                                                  OPTIONAL        -               0.6.32          OK         -

---

### | Python Extentions |

hpmudext             IO-Extension                                                 REQUIRED        -               3.17.4          OK         -
 cupsext              CUPS-Extension                                               REQUIRED        -               3.17.4          OK         -

---

### | DISCOVERED SCANNER DEVICES |

device `hpaio:/usb/Deskjet_3050_J610_series?serial=CN18J3D15405HX' is a Hewlett-Packard Deskjet_3050_J610_series all-in-one

---

### | DISCOVERED USB DEVICES |

Device URI                                              Model

---

hp:/usb/Deskjet_3050_J610_series?serial=CN18J3D15405HX  HP Deskjet 3050 J610 series

---

### | INSTALLED CUPS PRINTER QUEUES |

### Deskjet_3050_J610

Type: Printer
Device URI: hp:/usb/Deskjet_3050_J610_series?serial=CN18J3D15405HX
PPD: /etc/cups/ppd/Deskjet_3050_J610.ppd
warning: Failed to read /etc/cups/ppd/Deskjet_3050_J610.ppd ppd file
PPD Description: 
Printer Rendering completedkjet_3050_J610 disabled since Fri 21 Apr 2017 10:59:05 PM EDT -
error: Device busy: hp:/usb/Deskjet_3050_J610_series?serial=CN18J3D15405HX
error: Device not found
error: Communication status: Failed

---

### | PERMISSION |

USB             Deskjet_3050_J610              Required        -        -        OK       Node:'/dev/bus/usb/003/007' Perm:'  root  lp rw- rw- rw- rw- r--'

---

### | SUMMARY |

### Missing Required Dependencies

None

### Missing Optional Dependencies

None

Total Errors: 1
Total Warnings: 0
Done.

jon@faltinPC:~$ lsusb
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:8001 Intel Corp. 
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:8009 Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 003: ID 0461:4d0f Primax Electronics, Ltd HP Optical Mouse
Bus 003 Device 004: ID 413c:2006 Dell Computer Corp. 
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 413c:1004 Dell Computer Corp. 
Bus 003 Device 007: ID 03f0:9311 Hewlett-Packard 
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub